# git autosetuprebase is not working?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I have set up git with

```
git config --global branch.autosetuprebase always
```

and it looks ok in my `~/.gitconfig`file:

```
[branch]
    autosetuprebase = always
```

Yet when I do

```
git pull
```

he performs a merge (I removed company specific data):

```
From gitlab:***/***
    8fd1d96..0d064a3  master     -> origin/master
 * [new tag]         *** -> ***
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
```

Why doesn't he perform rebase? Note that the only thing he pulled from remote was a tag and a minor code change in a file not changed locally...

**edit**: I have git version 1.8.4.5

**edit**: this is my local `.git/config` file:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        logallrefupdates = true
[branch "master"]
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@gitlab:***/***.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: did u checked local .git config file. is it overwriting it ?

Comment: @SukhmeetSingh: I added it in my question... it is not overwriting the autosetuprebase option.

Comment: Perhaps you missed the part in `git help config` that says "When a new branch is created with git branch or git checkout that tracks another branch...". I don't think `autosetuprebase` will retroactively affect branches you already have in your repo (like `master`). You'll have to tweak those ones manually...

Comment: @twalberg that might explain; then is there no way to do this automatically for each of my git repositories and branches? (except scripting...)

Comment: Well, you can `git config branch.master.rebase true`... Replace `master` with the name of any other branch you want to do the same for. If you have lots of repos/branches to do this to, scripting it is probably the way to go...

Comment: ok, can you post this as an answer? It seems the good answer to me... tx!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `branch.autosetuprebase` option in `git` only affects branches created after it is set. From the manual page (`git help config`):

```
  branch.autosetuprebase
       When a new branch is created with git branch or git checkout that tracks another branch, this variable
       tells Git to set up pull to rebase instead of merge (see "branch.<name>.rebase"). When never, rebase is ...
```

For branches that already exist, e.g. `master`, there is `git config branch.master.rebase true`, which can be scripted for multiple branches/repos if necessary.